# Manually chaining Express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently use 2 middlewares:

[Express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) which extracts/validates a JsonWebToken from a request and my own middleware that checks that the JWT contains specific information (permissions).

I want to conditionally use those middlewares together (based on whether there's a specific swagger attribute on a route).

I want to do something like this:

```
let expressjwt = function(req, res, next) { ... };
let jwtValidator = function(req, res, next) { ... };

app.use((res, req, next) => {
    if(req.swagger.someAttribute) {
        expressjwt(req, res, jwtValidator(req, res, next));
        // The issue here is that jwtValidator will get called even if 
        // expressjwt produces an error
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are passing the jwtValidator to the expressjwt? Why can't you just call the first and then the second?

Comment: Because expressjwt is asynchronous and will call it's last argument when it's done, with an error or without (middleware convention)

Comment: @Charlie I updated with what I did, hopefully this helps (thanks for the reminder, btw).

Comment: ok please mark as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the question is - "how do you conditionally call service B only if service A succeeds."

This is one of main goals of promises - it allows you to chain together async calls and have them conditionally "resolve." I can post a code sample if needed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping my first middleware in a Promise using `Promise.fromCallback`, from memory, something like this:

```
if (req.swagger.someAttribute) {
  Promise.fromCallback(cb => expressjwt(req, res, cb))
    .then(() => {
      return jwtValidator(req, res, next);
    })
    .catch(next); // Or deal with the rejection
} else {
  next();
}
```

`Promise.fromCallback` is useful because `next()` is only called with arguments if the middleware failed and thus will become `promise.reject`